# How to pass a value into a SqlDataSource Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a ListView in ASP.NET and have based mine on the example given by CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5?msg=4387997#xx4387997xx).  I want to make the Select Command of the SqlDataSource dynamic so that a value is generated from one provided from the session.  Ive tried a fue different possibilities, here is an example of what I want:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Name] = <%# Eval("value") %> " >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How would I pass such a value using ASP?  Ive also tried creating the query in the C# back page and linking to it like `SelectCommand = "<%# Eval("Query") %>"` and also by using the `@value` syntax. neither work!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Define a **SessionParameter** as follows and make sure `Name=Sql parameter name and SessionField is same as your session field`. DBType and DefaultValue as required...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectCommandType="Text"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Name] = @ParaName"

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter 
               Name="ParaName" 
               SessionField="YourSessionFieldName" 
               DbType="String" 
               DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: This is a decent workaround, but I think the user would be better off programatically setting the data and binding it to a control rather than using a SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Name] = @Name"
```

And define your @Name as parameter

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter  DefaultValue="<%# Eval("Query") %>" Name="Name"  DbType="..." />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this now, but how can I get the "<%# Eval("Query") %>" of an item from the parent DataList?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided are very good.  It should also be noted that trying to place your "value" directly in the query, you are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.  Using the select parameters prevents and protects you from this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my lazy approach to solving it was to do as follows:

```
command.CommandText = item.Query.Replace("@Value", Value);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Dirty, easy and most likely not the proper way to do it.

Comment: This is not good. It opens your query up to a sql injection attack.  Never directly replace variables in a SQL query without scrubbing them first.

Comment: Like I stated, not the proper way to do it, also doesn't cause an issue if you have already validated Value before doing the replacement

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend against using a `SqlDataSource` control. A `SqlDataSource` provides very little in the realm is reuse.

**Programatically make the DB call**

If you make the call in a separate class (or even better in a `DAL`) you will be able to use it across multiple pages with ease. Also, when a change occurs to your query you will just have to change it in one place.

Here is a sample below that uses the Entity Framework to access the database

**Mark up**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server"></asp>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public List<Record> GetAllRecordsByUserName(string credentials)
{
    List<Record> recordList;
    using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
    {

        IQueryable<Record> recordQuery = from records in context.Records
                                              where records.UserName == credentials
                                              select records; 
        recordList = recordQuery.ToList<Record>();
    }
    return recordList;
}

public void ValidateAndBind(string username)
{
    List<Record> recordList = GetAllRecordsByUserName(username);

    // Do validation here

    ddlTest.DataSource = recordList;
    ddlTest.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateAndBind("test.username");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve your goal without code behind is using an **Hidden Field** and doing the following:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HfieldID" Value='<%# Eval("value")%>'/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Name] = @Name">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Name" PropertyName="Value" ControlID="HfieldID" DbType="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Be sure to put this ***before any controls*** that will use this SqlDataSource.