# ASP.NET SqlDataSource want to put <%# Bind("StateID") %> into SelectCommand but fail with a message "The server tag is not well formed."

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I wish to select the city name from tblCity Where the StateID will refer to the <%# Bind("StateID") %> but received with the error  "The server tag is not well formed."
Is there any missing part in my coding? Appreciate for helping. Thanks.
Below is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CityName] FROM [tblCity] WHERE [StateID] = "+ '<%# Bind("StateID") %>' + ""></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I try with replacing into WHERE.... @sID and using parameter but got error also with "The Parameter control with a two-way databinding to field StateID must have an ID."  Below is the code... 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand ="SELECT [CityName] FROM [tblCity] WHERE [StateID] = @sID">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%# Bind("StateID") %>' Name="sID" /></SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: what control are you using gridview or repeater ?

Comment: I am using the gridview, and I want to use it in EditItemTemplate dropdownlist...

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityUpdate" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("City") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="CityName" DataValueField="CityName" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCityUpdate_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>`

This is the drop downlist i using for the SqlDataSource3 ... Thanks

Comment: Because i just want let the dropdownlist show the city of the state, if i didn't put "Where StateID = xxx" it will show all the city including city in other state...

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144881/8843451

Comment: @Sund'er wow! u saved my problem thanks! hidden id helped me to get the ID Thanks! Really! have a good day~

Answer (score 0):

You can't use binding expressions in a sql paramter.

So you have to note or suggest where that value supposed to come from???

eg say like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CityName] FROM [tblCity] WHERE [StateID] = @StateP">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter 
            ControlID="txtState" PropertyName="Text"
            Name="StateP" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />    
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So, in above we set @StateP parameter as type string, and set the control id on the page where the state is to come from (a text box control called txtState).

But you have that <%#   -- and that type of expression is only for binding expressions - of which you don't have for sql parameters.

I guess we need more information where the value StateID  is to come from.